# How to set environment-variable in SpringBootTest for logback?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, logback, spring-boot-test

How to set environment variable for SpringBootTest for logback configuration?

**Logback configuration error** occurs when using a environment variable in logback.xml.

In logback.xml,

```
<appender name="plainLogsToFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/${LOG_PATH}/service.log</file>
```

This is the test-class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyTestClass {
//tests here
}
```

Following exception is reported:

```
openFile(/LOG_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED/service.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /LOG_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED/service.log (No such file or directory)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
```

I used ways to set property values explicitly using **@TestPropertySource** , **@ActiveProfiles("test")** , **@SpringBootTest(... , properties ={})** .

But, logback only refers system environment variables.

I am concerned only about test execution.

Some way to ignore the logback also appreciated.

Comment: You could set it in `@Before` method: `System.setProperty(key, value)`. Or, just put this in a `static` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either `@Before`, `@BeforeAll` or a `static` code block is *too late* to configure such variables for Logback.

You can solve this with a custom JUnit 5 extension:

```
public class PropertyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
    System.out.println("Setting system property");
    System.setProperty("LOG_PATH", "/my/logpath/for/testing");
  }

}
```

and use it within your test like:

```
@ExtendWith(PropertyExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyTestClass {

}
```

You can achieve the same with JUnit 4 with a custom `ClassRule`. Read more on this [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules).

In addition, you might also set a [default](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/the-logback-manual/content/en/chapter-3-configuration/configuration-file-syntax/variable-substitution.html) for such variables:

```
<appender name="plainLogsToFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/${LOG_PATH:-/tmp/default}/service.log</file>
</appender>
```